# C# process task manager kill running file

Tags: c#, taskmanager

I try to open file using process in C#, but after that file end work.

It is not end from task manager.

I am running this by thread

how i can kill fping.exe from task manager after specific time

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = currentDirectory;
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/fping.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = pingcmd;

cmd.Start();
```

Comment: have you tried using cmd.Kill() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you done working with the Process class, you should dispose of it.
To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/finally block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using

Here is example with **using**

```
using(Process cmd = new Process()){
   cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = currentDirectory;
   cmd.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/fping.exe";
   cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = pingcmd;

   cmd.Start();
}
```

Comment: We have a problem that sometimes fping.exe stops working for no reason so it can't complete its work

Comment: Check the link http://omegacoder.com/?p=119. The post explained more detail about process.